# How to get the name of the type of a ServiceReference?

Tags: osgi

I have a `ServiceReference` instance of which I want to get the name of the type it is registered as.

For example, the service may be a `WordService`, implemented by `WordServiceImpl`. I would like to retrieve `"WordService"`. `ServiceReference.toString()` gives me something close to what I want (`"[org.example.WordService]"`).

However, I'm assuming the `toString()` format isn't standard across runtimes. Also, I'd rather not inspect the interfaces of the implementing type to manually look for the interface, as I'd still have to randomly pick the right one in case of multiple interfaces.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly, but I actually figured it out almost immediately after posting.

Retrieve the value of the `objectClass` property through the service reference:

```
String[] objectClass = (String[]) reference.getProperty("objectClass");
```

As you can see, this is an array of `String`s. In my test cases, the first and only entry contained the provided service interface (`org.example.WordService`). I'm assuming multiple entries would appear if the implementation provides services through multiple interfaces.

I'm assuming this is standard OSGi...

Comment: It's standard OSGI, part of the spec. http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#OBJECTCLASS